# Return row if non existent in other table

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have 2 tables

```
members
=======
id
f_name  // get these values.
l_name
email

friends
=======
to
from
```

The users's I'd is the value $member_id, if it is present in "to" or "from" I want it to not return the other value of that row, so only non-friends are shown.

Im creating a page to allow members to search through the database to add their friends by email, or name.

I'd like to return all rows from members where there is no record of the userid in either the "to" or "from" columns of the friends table.

I know how to do most basic mysql but joins are an issue for me, i don't really understand how to write them, if anyone can help me out and maybe even explain it a bit that would be great!

```
My query now:
  $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE f_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR l_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR mc_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR email LIKE '%" . $word . "%' LIMIT 10";
//Where $word is the search term.
```

Modified Query

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT to FROM friends WHERE frm=$member_id) AND $member_id NOT IN (SELECT frm FROM friends WHERE to=$member_id) AND f_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR l_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR mc_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR email LIKE '%" . $word . "%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: And .. what have you tried so far?

Comment: i posted my current query ill also add my while statement getting the values if that is relevant.

Comment: It'd help if you put all the columns of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited

So, suppose a user with id 3:

```
SELECT * 
FROM members
WHERE id <> 3 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT to FROM friends WHERE from = 3)
AND id NOT IN (SELECT from FROM friends WHERE to = 3)
[Other conditions....];
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM members
LEFT JOIN friends
ON (members.id = friends.to
    OR members.id = friends.from)
AND (members.to = 3 
     OR members.from = 3)
WHERE friends.to IS NULL
AND id <> 3
[Other conditions....];
```

Maybe consider change the name of your "from" and "to" columns, to avoid confusion, because FROM and TO are reserved words.

Also, you can use the reserved word EXPLAIN , before the query, to see the difference of the number of rows being fetched.

Comment: SELECT * FROM members WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT to FROM friends WHERE frm=$member_id) AND $member_id NOT IN (SELECT frm FROM friends WHERE to=$member_id) AND f_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR l_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR mc_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR email LIKE '%" . $word . "%' LIMIT 10     This is what i have now.

Comment: You want to list all the "non-friends"? or just know if a member has no friends?

Comment: yeah i want to list all the non friends of the user, the friend requests are saved in the friends table with the to and frm columns being the id's of the 2 friends.

Comment: Ok, so
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE id <> " . $member_id . " 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT to FROM friends WHERE from = " . $member_id .") 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT from FROM friends WHERE to = " . $member_id . ")
AND (f_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' 
OR l_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%'
OR mc_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%'
OR email LIKE '%" . $word . "%')
LIMIT 0, 10;

Comment: $query = "SELECT * 
    FROM members m
 LEFT JOIN friends f
 ON m.id = f.to OR m.id = f.frm
 WHERE (f.to = $member_id OR f.frm = $member_id) AND (f_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR l_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR mc_name LIKE '%" . $word . "%' OR email LIKE '%" . $word . "%') LIMIT 10 ";

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that using an LEFT Join, which will return all rows from members even if there's no corresponding row on the friend's table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, f.* FROM members m LEFT JOIN friends f
```

A great article to understand the many joins there are is [this one.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: what im trying to do is like the oppisite of a join though if the value is not in the friends table it should show the result. Im still reading the article.

Comment: Hum, then I guess you're right.. perhaps then something like:
SELECT a.*, f.* FROM members m LEFT JOIN friends f ON a.id = f.id WHERE f.to IS NULL and f.from IS NULL